# Xcode поиск проблемного места в lldb

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Не совсем понимаю как работает дебаггинг в Xcode, по этому хотел узнать, можно ли узнать где идет обращение к `null` если приложение вылетает с пустым lldb в консоли, т.е. не написанно где проблема, и показывает проблемную строку в Ассемблерном виде типа:

> 0x70dc3e0 <+48>:  cmpl   $0x0, -0x8(%edx)

Знаю что проблема в том что идет обращение к null объекту, но при этом уже везде поставил проверки на `null` и проверил через Breakpoint'ы, проблема не находится.
При этом вылет полностью рандомный, может вообще не появиться, а может прям с ходу.

Есть предположение что проблема в `SKAction`, и по этому не показывает вылет на конкретной строке, т.к. проблема возникает во время анимации, но из-за рандомности вылета это протестировать толком невозможно.

**UPD:**

Отловить этот `exc_bad_access` так и неудолось.. я правильно понимаю что способов отладки `exc_bad_access` кроме `NSZombie` нет, и в таком случае только методом тыка пробовать?

Comment: а как вы определили что это обращение к null?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko "Thread 5: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)". "po 0x0" выдает nil

Comment: было бы странно если бы po 0x0 выдал что то другое :)

Comment: начните с exception breakpoint и symbolic breakpoint, может что выплывет. (command+7 и снизу слева плюс)

Comment: @xXxxX и можно пожалуйста весь код ошибки увидеть, что то очень странно, что он ничего не пишет более. И если действительно идет обращение к null объекту, то отследить это можно через Instrument (профилировщик), использую NSZombie.

Comment: @ИльяТерезников [Скрин](http://s020.radikal.ru/i706/1602/e6/512f216bde97.png) - всегда одна и та же ошибка, но в рандомные моменты, видно нужны какие то определенные стечения обстоятельств что бы она вылезла. За наводку NSZombie спасибо, но как на зло стоит его включить, как ошибка пропадает.

Comment: @ИльяТерезников С включенным NSZombie не получается вызвать ошибку ни в самом Xcode, ни в Instrument. Видно ошибка и в правду в анимациях, т.к. с NSZombie она немного подтормаживает, и видно это выигрывает время что бы объект раньше времени не очистился.

Comment: @xXxxX нужен код ошибки в консоли, он ее в консоль всю пишет.

Answer (score 1):

Если со включенным Zombie проблема исчезает, значит где-то идет обращение к объекту, указатель на который хранится в виде weak reference и он успевает обнулиться. А иногда не успевает, отсюда и случайность появления ошибки.

Хорошо бы увидеть код.

Comment: weak к сожалению нигде не используется. Но мысль понял.